# I am getting error App webApplicationInfo or resource not defined in manifest while using Microsoft SSO in task module

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

This is my manifest file and this is working correctly in case of messaging extension but not working in the case of the bot. I am trying to open a task module when action-type is task/fetch. I have added webApplicationInfo and resource correctly but still, I am getting this error.

```
  "webApplicationInfo": {
    "id": "abcdef",
    "resource": "api://abcd.ngrok.io/abcdef"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently SSO is not supported by Bots, it is supported by Tabs & Task module only.We are working on full support for Bots.

Comment: It is working in case of messaging extension and whenever I try to open the task module via some adaptive card then I get this error. As per doc, it should work.

Comment: Yes, it will work for task module as i mentioned but opening the task module from bot with SSO is not supported yet.

Comment: Please let me know, when can we expect the support of SSO in the bot task module?